# Syntax Error, Elif Statement

Tags: python

I get a syntax error on the 4<sup>th</sup> statement (`duration2 =="2" :`), but it is the same as the other lines. How do I fix the error?

```
if duration2 == "0.5":
    afterpitchx2 = (math.cos(befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note
    afterpitchy2 = (math.sin(befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note 
elif duration2 == "1":
    afterpitchx2 = (math.cos(befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note
    afterpitchy2 = (math.sin(befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note   
elif duration2 == "1.5" :
    afterpitchx2 = (math.cos(befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note
    afterpitchy2 = (math.sin((befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note 
elif duration2 == "2" :
    afterpitchx2 = (math.cos((math.pi/4)+befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note
    afterpitchy2 = (math.sin((math.pi/4)+befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note 
elif duration2 == "3" :
    afterpitchx2 = (math.cos((0.375*math.pi)+befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note
    afterpitchy2 = (math.sin((0.375*math.pi)+befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note
elif duration2 == "4" :
    afterpitchx2 = (math.cos(befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note
    afterpitchy2 = (math.sin(befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note   
elif duration2 == "6" :
    afterpitchx2 = (math.cos(befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note
    afterpitchy2 = (math.sin(befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note   
elif duration2 == "8" :
    afterpitchx2 = (math.cos(befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note
    afterpitchy2 = (math.sin(befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note       
elif duration2 == "12" :
    afterpitchx2 = (math.cos(befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note
    afterpitchy2 = (math.sin(befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note
elif duration2 == "16" :
    afterpitchx2 = (math.cos(befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note
    afterpitchy2 = (math.sin(befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note
```

Comment: I this a question about Blender? This looks like a general Python language question

Comment: Hi Nick, i think you should ask this on a python page...it has nothing to do with blender....

Comment: Why cant you just do two if statements for the ones that need special math and then just put one else for the rest of the cases? That's just alot of extra code that does nothing in particular. Just like `if duration == "2": ... elif duration == "3": ... else: (math.sin(befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note; (math.cos(befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note`

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra parenthesis in the `duration2 == "1.5"` part on this line

```
afterpitchy2 = (math.sin((befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note
```

It should read

```
afterpitchy2 = (math.sin(befcounterdegrees))*pitch_note
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, my bad for not seeing that.